# Calculating periods given a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given a reference date, I want to calculate periods for next business day, next weekend, next week business days, and days until end of month

for example given 21-12-2017 i want to get

```
next business day -> 22-12-2017 / 22-12-2017
next weekend -> 23-12-2017 / 24-12-2017
next week business days->25-12-2017 / 29-12-2017
days until end of month ->22-12-2017 / 31-12-2017
```

How should I go about this? I already have a calendar table but I don't know how to do these without using subselects for each column

The calendar table looks like this

```
Date       DayOfWeek MonthStartDate MonthEndDate MonthLength IsWeekend
2017-12-21 4         2017-12-01     2017-12-31   31          0
```

Comment: it should be very easy with a calendar table. Can you show us how your calendar table looks like ?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Features like [`EOMONTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) may be useful.

Comment: edited to show what calendar table looks like.I'm on SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0):

example on how to use your calendar table

```
select  top 1 next_business_day = [Date]
from    calendar
where   [Date]  > '2017-12-21'
order by [Date]

select  top 2 next_weekend = [Date]
from    calendar
where   [Date]      > '2017-12-21'
and     IsWeekend   = 1
order by [Date]
```

for `next week business days`, if you can add a `week no` to you calendar table, it will be easier

Answer (score 0):

This uses my Calendar table, as I started working before you posted some of your (plus I needed something to test against).

One thing I noticed, is you state "next week business days" however, is  `20171225` - `20171229` therefore correct? The 25th is is Christmas day (not many places consider that day is a Business day).

Any way, you'll need to edit for your Calendar table, but let me know if this works:

```
DECLARE @Date Date = '20171221'

SELECT TOP 1
       FIRST_VALUE([date]) OVER (ORDER BY DD.[Working Day] DESC, DD.Date) AS NextWorkingDay,
       FIRST_VALUE([date]) OVER (ORDER BY CASE [Day Name] WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, DD.Date) AS WeekendStart,
       DATEADD(DAY, 1,FIRST_VALUE([date]) OVER (ORDER BY CASE [Day Name] WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, DD.Date)) AS WeekendEnd,
       FIRST_VALUE([date]) OVER (ORDER BY CASE [Day Name] WHEN 'Monday' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, DD.Date) AS NextWeekStart,
       DATEADD(DAY, 4,FIRST_VALUE([date]) OVER (ORDER BY CASE [Day Name] WHEN 'Monday' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, DD.Date)) AS NextWeekEnd,
       DATEADD(Day, 1, @Date) AS EndStart,
       DATEADD(DAY, -1, (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Date)+1, 0))) AS MonthEnd
FROM DimDate DD
WHERE DD.Date > @Date;
```

*I notice you don't have a Day name in your Calendar Table. I'd recommend adding this. Otherwise you'll need to change my references to `[Day Name]` to `DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[Date])` however, that will slow down the performance.*

Comment: 25th and 26th are holidays here but i was trying to keep it simple.I think I get the idea, thanks

Comment: 25th Dec is not a holiday in North Pole. If you don't believe ask `santa`